# Custom Enum in Java

Tags: java, enums, inner-classes

I need to implement custom Enum. It should some class which implements Enum methods like valueOf, values and ordinal without directly extending java.lang.Enum. I have been thinking about creating it in such a way where instead of the String should be some generic type T:

```
public class CustomEnum {
    private static int size;
    private static final InnerEnum enumValues;

    public CustomEnum(){

    }

    public String valueOf(String innerEnum, String name){
        if(name.equals(innerEnum)){
            return innerEnum;
        }
        return null;
    }

    public InnerEnum values(){
        return enumValues;
    }

    public int ordinal(){}

    public static class InnerEnum{
        public static String[] data;
        public static int number;
    }
}
```

I should be able to give some varying number of parameters (like using varargs) and create constants out of them plus all the enum methods. But I do not really know how to implement all of it. I would be very grateful if someone would help me with that!

Comment: So, there is a working solution in Java, which is the Java enum, but you don't want to use it, without an explanation why. And then you don't really know what to do, and you can't really explain what your problem is. Am I understanding that right? My suggestion: use Java enums until you understand what you can't do with them, and then ask here how to do that with enums.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt it's not that I don't want to use it. I have a task according to which I need to create a class which would act like enum.

Comment: Look at the source of java.lang.Enum class to have understanding how Enum functionality is implemented.